# Print value of multiple equal keys once time C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Good morning,
I have a multiple map defined in this way

```
multimap<string, string> H_test;
```

with value insered from user(multiple book written by the same author in a random order)

```
H_test.insert(pair<string, string>(author, book));
```

I would like to have as output something like that :

```
Author I // one author
Book A  // all book written by this author
Book B
Author II 
Book K
Author III
Book C
Book D
Book E
```

Using this code

```
for (multimap<string,string>::iterator it = H_test.begin(); it != H_test.end(); it++)
    {
        //if ()
        {
            pair <multimap<string, string>::iterator, multimap<string, string>::iterator> ret;
            ret = H_test.equal_range(it->first);
            std::cout << it->first << endl;
            for (multimap<string, string>::iterator sd = ret.first; sd != ret.second; sd++)
            {
                cout << "\t" << sd->second << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

I obtain this output

```
Author I
Book A
Book B
Author I
Book A
Book B
Author II
Book K
Author III
..
```

In my opinion, it prints the name of first key (and all the books which have the same author) and then it goes to the second nome (which has the same name), and re-write everything. 
Do you know how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: First, `it = H_test.begin(); it != Hiwi_test.end();` - you're comparing iterators from two *different* apparent containers ? A [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is warranted. Post one. And why you're not just using a `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>` seems a little odd, unless you're purposely wanting to explore multimaps.

Comment: Sorry I changed a little bit the code before publishing. Should be 
it = H_test.begin(); it != H_test.end();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound) is your friend. You'd want to use it something like this:

```
auto start = begin(H_test);

while (start != end(H_test)) {
    auto finish = H_test.upper_bound(start->first);

    cout << "Author: " << start->first << endl;
    for_each(start, finish, [](const auto& i) { cout << "Book: " << i.second << endl; });
    start = finish;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/UVBaDV)

Note: You can use `cbegin` and `cend` instead of if `H_test` is `const`.

**EDIT:**

It helps me to conceptualize a `multimap` as a sorted array of `pair`s, where the first element in the `pair` is the key and the second element is the value. Here's effectively what we'll do:

1. Iterate through all the `pair`s using `start` as our iterator, beginning at the first `pair`: `auto start = begin(H_test)` and going to the last `pair` in the `multimap`: `while(start != end(H_test))`
2. Next we want to find the range of `pair`s in the container that share the same key, for that we'll find an iterator pointing one past the end using the `upper_bound` function that I linked the details about above: `auto finish = H_test.upper_bound(start->first)`
3. We will print the current author who's books we just found in the range: `cout << "Author: " << start->first << endl`
4. Then we'll print each book in the range defined by `start` to `finish` using [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and a lambda to only print the value of the pair then move to the next line: `for_each(start, finish, [](const auto& i) { cout << "Book: " << i.second << endl; });`
5. Finally we'll set `start` to the beginning of the next range, which will be printed next time through the loop: `start = finish`

Comment: @Downvoter Can I get clarification on the reason for the downvote? As far as I know this is pretty much standard procedure for printing a `multimap`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you please explain me how does it work? I mean, you created a variable auto(??) and after a cicle you set start = finish. I didn't get what it do

Comment: @GVa I've updated my example with an explanation. If any of the steps are unclear lets revisit them in the comments here. As far as `auto` you can think of it as inline templating with a few side benefits. After C++11 you'll basically want to declare all your variables with `auto`, but the whole concept is to big to be defined in a comment (plus even though the language is pushing it, there are those who take issue with it.) In any case the preeminent document on it can be found here: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate through the multimap and since all the elements with the same author are grouped together, you just need to detect a change in author to know you have moved on to the next author at which time you print the name of the author. Preset the `lastAuthor` to something that won't potentially match a real author. This executes in O(n)

```
string lastAuthor = "**SENTINEL**";
for (const auto& elem : H_test)
{
  if(lastAuthor != elem.first)
  {
    cout << "Author: " << elem.first << '\n';
    lastAuthor = elem.first;
  }

  cout << "Book: " << elem.second << '\n';
}
```